# Remove default blue border when ctrl clicking table elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question has been asked before, but none of the answers worked for me.

Things I've tried :

event.preventDefault() - does nothing.

remove user-select from css - not feasible, user should be able to select text still.

remove select from event when ctrl+click - has a delay, only works after mouseup

Example of above :

```
document.body.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        //Select row logic here
        if (document.selection){
        document.selection.empty();
      }else if (window.getSelection){
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/zm1dgt3s/5/

This gets extra annoying when the user clicks "between" table cells, then it selects all cells.

Is there any elegant solution to this problem? No JQuery please

Answer (score 1):

I was just using the wrong event, mousedown is the correct one :

```
table.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate, you can use css for this - http://jsfiddle.net/Lgk0m27u/

Answer (score 0):

Do you try it with CSS?

```
div#myDiv:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: What impact on the border would that have?

Comment: This command will remove some things from elements when it is active, for example, blue border, underline selection and text purple color when clicked.

Comment: I do not see any div, active or not in the question. Please show example with and without your code.

Comment: I think i was undestanding wrong... I'm sorry.